# Как правильно организовать приём и обработку данных, полученных через webhook?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, webhook

Сервер, отправляющий webhook, ждет ответ в течении 5 секунд. За это время обработчик на php не успевает закончить работу и принять новое уведомление, поэтому данные с webhook нужно где-то хранить.

Сейчас работа с данными реализована следующим образом: скрипт, получающий webhook, записывает его содержимое в файл. Каждые 5 минут по крону запускается обработчик, он считывает все содержимое файла и выполняет необходимые действия, затем считывает файл заново и переписывает, оставляя лишь необработанные строки(те, что были записаны пока обработчик выполнялся).

Когда запросы поступают постепенно, все работает хорошо. Но если в файле накапливается много запросов, они начинают выполняться очень медленно.

Можно ли без кардинальных изменений улучшить существующие скрипты и как в принципе правильно работать с данными webhook?

Comment: Самый очевидный вариант реализовать очередь в виде таблицы в БД со столбиком "обработано". Это будет работать значительно быстрее, чем текстовый файл

Comment: Либо же использовать очередь задач, к примеру Gearman - создаёте очередь, и в неё кладёте задачи для обработки с данными. Как подходит время - запускаете рабочие процессы, которые будут работать над задачами в очереди. Все задачи обработали - закрываете рабочие процессы. По сути одно и тоже что предложено выше так как Gearman сериализует задачи в БД, единственное преимущество - параллельная обработка задач.